# Can't showdialog a form with threading

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to show a form in my winform app and I Used thread. like This:

`new System.Threading.Thread(s => new Form().ShowDialog()).Start();`

It works and form opens but not as a showDialog, as a show .Means I can open another form on it.
Any Idea????

Comment: Generally you should not do that - why do you want to use a new thread?

Comment: You should not interact with the UI on a background thread.